# Game theory and differential equations

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, mathematical-economics, ode

Does anybody know, any (advanced/classic) textbook that combines game theory with differential equations in mathematical economics. Specifically, I an interested in asymmetric information problems.

Comment: Why do you think ODEs are relevant to games with asymmetric information?

Comment: @Michael Greinecker, neither I know that, nor I think that they are relevant...I am still searching and I am asking if there is some textbook that mat contain also asymmetric information. If there is not then I am not going to paint it black

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, it is a field that i am eager to leran!

Comment: Weibull's [*Evolutionary Game Theory*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Evolutionary_Game_Theory.html?id=m98ed0_Na1sC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a chapter (Ch. 6) on ODE and its applications in evolutionary games.

Comment: If evolutionary game theory is an option then use https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/population-games-and-evolutionary-dynamics#preview-drawer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the intersection of differential equations and game theory one can find [differential games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_game). Arguably, the most famous applications of differential games are in warfare, e.g., the [homicidal chauffeur problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidal_chauffeur_problem). However, not all differential games are of the [pursuit-evasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit-evasion) kind.

Whoever wants to learn differential games may wish to learn optimal control theory first. To the neophyte, I would recommend Evans's book (chapter 6 is on games):

- Lawrence C. Evans, [An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eevans/control.course.pdf) [PDF], Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley.

The next step could be the following books on applications to economics:

- Engelbert J. Dockner, Steffen Jorgensen, Ngo Van Long, Gerhard Sorger, [Differential Games in Economics and Management Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=TMJWWMsE1_AC), Cambridge University Press, November 2000.
- Luca Lambertini, [Differential Games in Industrial Economics](https://books.google.com/books?id=aU9TDwAAQBAJ), Cambridge University Press, April 2018.

and, more on the stochastic side:

- David W. K. Yeung, Leon A. Petrosjan, [Cooperative Stochastic Differential Games](https://books.google.com/books?id=F8NNYgv7FKAC), Springer, May 2006.

Unlike Evans's book, I have never read these ones. My listing of these books is not an endorsement.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an old question. However there is a book on PDE's and game theory.

Game Theory and Partial Differential Equations, Pablo Blanc and Julio Daniel Rossi.

If you found other books on this matter, I would like to know as well.